# how to concatenate lines into one string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function in bash that outputs a bunch of lines to stdout. I want to combine them into a single line with some delimiter between them.

Before:

```
one 
two 
three
```

After:

```
one:two:three
```

What is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`paste`](http://ss64.com/bash/paste.html)

```
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | paste -s -d':'
one:two:three
```

Comment: that's the correct answer. I knew it there was some simple function kicking around to do exactly that.

Comment: On OSX, add an extra dash: ``$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | paste -s -d':' -``

Comment: It seems simpler with `tr` as it does `not` defer for different operating systems

Comment: @k00ka why dash is needed on OSX?

Comment: @ribitskiyb OSX's paste requires a <file> argument and the dash tells it to use stdin.

Answer (score 12):

And another way:

```
cat file | tr -s "\n" ":"
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
paste -sd':' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking @glennJackman's corrections verbatim

```
awk '{printf("%s%s", sep, $0); sep=":"} END {print ""}' file
```

Or as you specified bash

```
while read line ; do printf "%s:" $line ; done < file | sed s'/:$//'
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Interesting point... are `awk`/`paste`/`grep` etc not considered part of bash?

Comment: it all depends on your perspective. bash is a shell. awk/paste/grep etc work inside of any Unix-based shell: ash, bash, dash, ksh, rc, sh, zsh, et.al ;-)

Comment: These solutions emit a trailing colon. To avoid it, you could pipe into sed to remove it, or do something like: `awk '{printf("%s%s", sep, $0); sep=":"} END {print ""}'`

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's a bash-only way:

```
echo $'one\n2 and 3\nfour' | { mapfile -t lines; IFS=:; echo "${lines[*]}"; }
```

outputs

```
one:2 and 3:four
```

The `{}` grouping is to ensure all the commands that refer to the array variable are executed in the same subshell. The variable will not exist once the pipeline ends.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile-140

Answer (score 0):

Input.txt

> ```
> one
> two
> three
> ```

Perl Solution : dummy.pl

```
 @a = `cat /home/Input.txt`;
    foreach my $x (@a)
    {
            chomp($x);
            push(@array,"$x");
    }
    chomp(@array);
    print "@array";
```

Run the script as :

> $> perl dummy.pl | sed 's/ /:/g' > Output.txt

Output.txt

> one:two:three